# How to serialize stored JSON serialization (in Ruby/Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I'd like to store a JSON blob in my table (Postgres). The table needs to be read frequently. After my application reads the table, it returns a JSON serialization of this blob along with other attributes of this table to the client.

```
# To illustrate, imagine an object like this
{
  name: 'foo',
  blob: {...} # this is blob that needs to be stored
}
```

and when a client requests for it, I'd like to return a JSON response like

```
{"name": "foo", "blob": [...]}
```

Given a Postgres database, the obvious choice is to store blob in a json/jsonb column. But what about a text column? Assuming blob is not used by the application, storing a serialized string in a text column means server doesn't need to deserialize the blob then serialize back to JSON whenever the client sends a request. In other words, the server can simply treat the blob as a string. Sounds more efficient, right?

However, because blob is now treated as a string, the serialization I get becomes

```
{"name": "foo", "blob": "[...]"} # note the extra " around the array brackets
```

This leads to incorrect parsing in the client application since now blob is parsed as a string instead of an array.

So my question is

a. Am I correct in assuming that a text column will be more efficient than jsonb (assuming this problem is solved)?

b. if so, whether there's a way to return an already serialized JSON object without treating it as a string? If not, what's the best way to avoid this type of deserialize-then-immediately-serialize waste?

Comment: jsonb will be best. plus you can index and search on it too https://blog.codeship.com/unleash-the-power-of-storing-json-in-postgres/ also remember "...premature optimization is the root of all evil" ~ Knuth

Answer (score 2):

### Don't worry so much.

When you use JSON/JSONB columns in Rails the driver handles serializing/unserializing the JSON. All you have to do is declare the column as JSON/JSONB.

Storing JSON/YAML any other format in a text/varchar column is unlikely to give any noticeable performance gains BUT will not allow you to query the column properly. Thats what we did back in the dark days before we had native JSON/JSONB/HStore columns.

It also places the burden of marshalling/unmarshalling in your models - bloating them and forgoing the use of more optimized driver code.